# Trying to add an image in HTML?

Tags: html

I use `Sublime Text 3.0` to code html-based website. As indicated by my username, I'm not much of an expert. I'm having trouble adding an image with sublime text 3.0 using the latest `google chrome` browser version `44.0.2403.130 m` and I run windows 8.1 pro (still waiting for the upgrade to w10 Dx) anyway, I'm pretty sure my software isn't the problem. I can upload images using a externally linked image such as

> http://www.examplesite.com/picture.gif

and it will appear but when I try to upload from my own directory as such

```
<h1><img src="Logo.jpeg" alt="Logo"/>Prespective News</h1>
```

It will not show up on my web browser, it just shows the alternate text of Logo, is there something wrong with my code? Please help me, I've spent at least 4 hours. trying to figure it out! also it's all my pictures, not just 1.

The image is in the same directory as my HTML file is. When I do the `F12`, it shows an error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/Users/Owner/Documents/My%20Web%20Sites/Website%202/Logo.jpeg

This is confusing because this is exactly where my file is in:

> C:\Users\Owner\Documents\My Web Sites\Website 2\Logo.JPEG

The html file is in

> C:\Users\Owner\Documents\My Web Sites\Website 2\idk yet.HTML

Answer (score 1):

The img src URL you provided was probably incorrect. If you open chrome dev tools (F12) you should be able to see (on the network tab) where the image source you are *trying* to fetch is. Then you can compare it to the path your image *actually* resides.

**Things you can do:**

1. Check if the name matches the one you provide exactly (case sensitive)
2. Remember the sources you link are relative to your page, so if you put it in a folder it might need to be *src="images/Logo.jpeg"*
3. You might be using jpg instead of jpeg, please check that also.

Comment: I did not link an external image, when I do link an external image it shows up perfectly fine. I also have the file in the same directory to make it easy to get it with just the file name and the file type is JPEG

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind right now is whether you  have the same name in the src. The name is case sensitive so if your file is logo.JPEG it should be "logo.JPEG" in the src. You can try dragging the image to the browser, to see the full path of the image. You can try using that, then chopping down the file:// etc at the start up until you reach the image name. It should be working after that.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't show up it's because `Logo.jpeg` isn't in the same directory. Since your file name is `Logo.JPEG` it should be:

```
<h1><img src="Logo.JPEG" alt="Logo"/>Prespective News</h1>
```

Capitalisation matters.

Comment: this is my directory :\Users\Owner\Documents\My Web Sites\Website 2 and my image is in there, with the file name Logo and type of file as JPEG image (.JPG)

Comment: @MadNoviceCoder Your file is called `Logo.JPEG` not `Logo.jpeg`. Capitalisation matters.

Answer (score 0):

When coding a website you should keep all the required images in a separate image folder and use the source address appropriately.
Suppose you have an image folder in your current working directory then use
`img src="image/logo.jpg" />`

Comment: I did not do this because I have 2 separate website directories and I wanted to just put the file name instead of doing the "/images/pic.jpeg" saves me time to just put "pic.jpeg"

Comment: which browser are you using??

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is your image not found in your specific folder.
Provide correct folder name for the image path. This issue can be easily solved. Use Firebug or F12 keys for troubleshooting.

Comment: I did that, the folder that the browser is looking into is the correct one, but I have no idea why it doesn't show.

Comment: Share both of your programming file path,and your image path also if you have any redirections

Comment: C:\Users\Owner\Documents\My Web Sites\Website 2\Logo.JPEG                   C:\Users\Owner\Documents\My Web Sites\Website 2\idk yet.HTML

Answer (score 0):

I usually put my images in a folder aside to the html file so in the same directory

```
<img src="images/image.jpg" alt="image" title="image of an image" /> <h1>Titre1</h1>
```

Try it this way maybe. I would seperate the title h1 from the image.

Comment: I also have multiple images because I figured it was proximity to other attributes causing problems but alas, they too don't show. When I link it from a different website it shows perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong. Turns out the file is a JPEG but for some reason it's extension is .JPG not with an E. I'm not sure why it's not listed as a .JPEG since the file type is JPEG, anyway thank you for your responses ya'll! I probably wouldn't have figured it out if I wasn't responding and looking at the picture information xD

Comment: It can be named anything. It could be named **adsdljsdflsdjf.mp4** and still be a JPEG. The filename is the full name i.e. **Logo.JPG**, the format is the file content. They are only linked by naming convention **.jpeg, .jpg, .JPG, .JPEG** not by any enforced rule.

Comment: oh alright, let me try to make sense of it since I was struggling with this for so long. Even though my file type is a **JPEG** the extension of it is `.JPG` regardless of the name or type?

Comment: JPEG is an image format. Extension is just what we call the portion after the dot. You can have a filename like say **hosts** (which you have in windows) that **is** a text file. On average files have an appropriate extension like **.txt**, **.psd*, **.gif** with JPEGs it's common to end in either **.jpg** or **.jpeg**. Similarly HTML is often named either **.htm** or **.html**. This is due to ancient versions of windows not supporting extensions longer than 3 characters, so it was historically truncated (this hasn't been necessary for a long time). Yes, it can be named .jpg regardless of type

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much for the thorough answer, this truly put extensions into prespective. _I will be paying much more attention to extensions from now on!_ **Thank you again Kit!**